# Residue of Pole $s=1$ of $\zeta$ function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I have trouble to understand Why the residue of the riemann $\zeta$ function is 1. I can just find that One can see this because $\lim_{s\to 1} (s-1)\zeta(s)=1$. But I do not understand how to get the 1 by using the Series representation $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$

Comment: No, it's not at all obvious from this Dirichlet series definition that the residue at the first pole is $1$. But: you can estimate the series by the obvious integral, with an error that is a holomorphic function of $s$ up to $\Re(s)=1/2$. The integral is elementary, giving the residue.

Comment: $$\zeta(s)-\frac{s}{s-1}= (\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^\infty s x^{-s-1}dx )- \int_1^\infty s x^{-s}dx = s \int_1^\infty (\lfloor x \rfloor - x) x^{-s-1}dx$$ converges and is holomorphic for $\Re(s) > 0$ @paulgarrett

Comment: Could you also use the integral representation for $\zeta(s)$ in terms of $\Gamma(s)$?

Comment: When I compute $\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} s(s-1)\int_{1}^{n} (\lfloor x \rfloor - x)x^{-s-1} \cdot dx$ for small values of $n$ (e.g. $n=2, 3, 4, 5$, I end up with $0$. How does this limit end up being $1$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: How do you show that $\lim_{s - 1} s(s-1) \int_{1}^{\infty} ((\lfloor x \rfloor) - x)x^{-s-1} =  1$?

Comment: I apologize; I mean how do you show that $s(s-1)\lim_{s \rightarrow 1} \int_{1}^{\infty} (\lfloor x \rfloor - x)x^{-s-1}  dx =0$ ?

Comment: I think it’s because  |\lfloor x \rfloor| is bounded from above by 1.

Answer (score 0):

The limit becomes much easier to grasp if you use the alternating series representation, $$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{1 - 2^{1-s}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}.$$ The alternating sum equals $\log(2)$ for $s=1$, so what you have to evaluate is the limit of $\frac{s - 1}{1 - 2^{1-s}}$. By using L'Hôpital's rule, this equals $1 / \log(2)$, so that the limit is $\log(2) / \log(2) = 1$.